# How to get list of subscribers of any channel (not only mine) using youtube api with python?

Tags: python, youtube-api

I am trying to get list subscribers of any channel using youtube api using python. But i am getting issue when i run my code it asks me to enter authorisation code and i do not know what it is. I have also enabled oath api. see my code below
import os

```
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import googleapiclient.errors

flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file("client_secrets.json", 
                            scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"])
flow.run_local_server(port=8080, prompt="consent")
credentials = flow.run_console()
youtube = build("youtube", "v3", credentials=credentials)
request = youtube.subscriptions.list(
        part="snippet,contentDetails",
        channelId="UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw"
)
response = request.execute()
print(response)
```

is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that every YouTube channel doesn't have its subscriptions public (in fact they are private by default, see [youtube.com/account_privacy](https://www.youtube.com/account_privacy)).

However if they are public, they are available on the:

1. YouTube UI at
   [youtube.com/channel/CHANNEL_ID/channels?view=56&shelf_id=0](https://www.youtube.com/channel/CHANNEL_ID/channels?view=56&shelf_id=0)
2. YouTube Data API v3 [Subscriptions:
   list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list)
   (you don't need to authenticate to retrieve them as they are
   public). Just retrieve
   [googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&channelId=CHANNEL_ID&key=API_KEY](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&channelId=CHANNEL_ID&key=API_KEY).

More precisely this Python code does the job:

```
import googleapiclient.discovery

youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build("youtube", "v3", developerKey="API_KEY")

request = youtube.subscriptions().list(
    part="snippet,contentDetails",
    channelId="CHANNEL_ID"
)
response = request.execute()
print(response)
```

Example of YouTube channel having public subscriptions: [UCt5USYpzzMCYhkirVQGHwKQ](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCt5USYpzzMCYhkirVQGHwKQ)

Note: if the channel's subscriptions are private, you'll hit a

> Encountered 403 Forbidden with reason "subscriptionForbidden"
>
> // Traceback ...
>
> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&channelId=CHANNEL_ID&key=API_KEY&alt=json returned "The requester is not allowed to access the requested subscriptions.". Details: "[{'message': 'The requester is not allowed to access the requested subscriptions.', 'domain': 'youtube.subscription', 'reason': 'subscriptionForbidden'}]">

[subscriptions.list errors documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#subscriptions_youtube.subscriptions.list)

Comment: Why do we use YouTube Data Api for this operation and not a direct browse of channel's subscribers with a typical https GET/POST request? what is the difference?

Comment: The API is designed for such kind of purpose while web scraping is against YouTube ToS so you don't have any guarantee that your web scraping request will return a successful response. Thanks to [quota](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost), the API usage is limited.